# Change Refresh rate on hyperv_fb driver

Tags: centos, hyper-v, refresh-rate

I'm using a guest CentOS 7 in HyperV.
I managed to change the resolution of the screen, but it has a really low refresh rate.

Is there a way to improve the refresh rate?

Comment: Are you able to confirm that this isn't network lag?

Comment: Yes it isn't. It's in my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake.

I didn't specified particularly to use all avaialable processors.
HyperV only assigned 1 virtual processor to the virtual machine, adding more solved the issue.